# Is there a way using GRAPE to trap all exceptions within the API instead of showing HTML error page

Tags: ruby, api, exception, ruby-grape

We are using Grape to provide a API; the API raises exceptions in a lot of places randomly because of insufficient parameters, nils etc. This causes Rails to produce an HTML error page. 
Is there a way to control this and wrap all calls to return an error message instead?

We are using

## API

```
gem 'grape', '0.9'
gem 'grape-swagger', '0.8.0'
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
```

For example:
if any error occurs in the API, it does not reach

```
rescue ArgumentError => ex
    error! ex.message
rescue Mongoid::Errors::Validations => ex
    error! ex.message
```

of the API method.
We need a way to catch exact error message bypassing the HTML error page.

Already tried this

> https://code.dblock.org/2011/05/04/grape-trapping-all-exceptions-within-the-api.html

not sure where to inject the ApiErrorHandler .

Expected results should be **"result: xyz error message"**

Comment: The documentation you linked shows where you inject it. Do so inside your class which inherits from `Grape::API`

Answer (score 1):

> not sure where to inject the ApiErrorHandler

In your Grape controller:

```
require 'api_error_handler'

class Api_v1 < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  version 'v1'

  use ApiErrorHandler

  ...
end
```

Code example from an [`article`](https://code.dblock.org/2011/05/04/grape-trapping-all-exceptions-within-the-api.html) you linked

---

Or you can catch exceptions in helper method. Something like:

```
module ActionsHelper
  extend Grape::API::Helpers

  def request_with_error_handling(options = { status: 422 }, &block)
    raise ArgumentError, 'Options are nil' if options.nil?
    raise ArgumentError, 'No block given' unless block_given?

    yield

    rescue Mongoid::Errors::Validations => ex
      error! ex.message
    rescue ArgumentError => ex
      error! ex.message
  end
end

# users as an example
class Users < Grape::API
  namespace :users do
    helpers ActionsHelper

    desc 'Create new user'
    params do
      # user params
    end
    post '/' do
      request_with_error_handling do
        # your user creation logic here
        # any exception would be catched 
        # in request_with_error_handling helper method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with your setup, but Grape has built in way of doing this kind of thing.  From the documentation:

```rb
class Twitter::API < Grape::API
  rescue_from ArgumentError do |e|
    Rack::Response.new([ "ArgumentError: #{e.message}" ], 500).finish
  end
  rescue_from NotImplementedError do |e|
    Rack::Response.new([ "NotImplementedError: #{e.message}" ], 500).finish
  end
end
```